# Admin edit of older order forces to add values to newly added required fields

Tags: 7, commerce

In our drupal-commerce e-shop orders were already working for more than a year. Later we wanted to add some required fields (phone number and "I agree with ...." checkbox), phone field few months back and the checkbox just recently (as part of GDPR-ready effor).

Today we realized that admin editing of order to move it in workflow (change state) forces the admin to fill-in the phone number field and to check the checkbox. That is not good.

Also it looks that in order list is the name of admin now ... for those edited orders.

Does anyone know how to fix this behaviour? Any existing issue? We just want to be able to change the order state and not to change anything else.

Versions: Drupal 7.59, Commerce 7x-1.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you resolve this depends on your Drupal version, so please be sure to specify Drupal 7 vs. Drupal 8 in future questions. On Drupal 8, you can likely resolve this by editing the form display mode and not including those fields on the normal admin form. However, in Drupal 7 you'll have no such option. You'll need to use hook_form_alter() to prevent those fields from showing up on the order edit form instead.

Re: the administrator name, there's no way for us to help you without knowing how you've constructed that View. If it's just showing the name of the last person to edit the order (i.e. create a revision of it), it makes sense that it'd be the administrator. It should normally be pulling the name from the order's billing information profile.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with versions (sorry I forgot that). Unfortunately I have Drupal 7. And views ... I have standard orders view from commerce admin pages.

Answer (score 1):

If administer is not same as user 1, then a simple trick could be ban administration role from editing those fields using [Field Permissions Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions).

else as user with ID 1 bypasses many restriction, then as Ryan said, you should have implement [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) in a custom module and simply `unset` those fields or remove the required attributes.